# Using props value in style property

Tags: vue.js

I have the following element:

```
  <div :style="{'width': width}"></div>
```

With the following props script:

```
export default {
  props: {
    width: {
      type: String,
      default: '100px'
    }
  }
};
</script>
```

What exactly am I doing here that doesn't work? Do I have to use a `compute` to do this?

Comment: it seems work, did you try something like `<div :style="{'width': width}" style="height:50px;background-color:green"></div>`?

Comment: @BoussadjraBrahim I haven't got any other styles at all! It compiles to `<div style=""></div>` :(

Comment: Oh for god's sake, looks like it was to do with caching - thanks